# How to get text or json data from python request post

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying extract data from this webiste [URL](https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA&DCC=IT&currency=EUR)

Where price seems to dynamically updated so hard to extract from `beautifulsoup` but when i try to find data from xhr or Network tab data is present so i tried below code to get json data

Code:

```
import requests
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA&DCC=IT&currency=EUR"
}
data={"anno": 3,
"client": "te_lib",
"format": "html",
"v": "1.0",
"key": "AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw",
"logld": "vTE_20210503_00",
"sl": "it",
"tl": "en",
"tc": "1",
"dom": "1",
"sr":"1",
"tk": "736161.909205",
"mode": "1"}


response=requests.post("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/t?",params=data,headers=headers,v)
response.text
```

Output:

```
'""'
```

> So as per code it did not return any output so is how to get data from it.

Data in Network tab:
[image]

and also from headers`content-disposition: attachment; filename="f.txt"` it shows this and when i click on that link it download the file which also does not contain any data

Comment: What is it you are trying to scrape?

Comment: I want value 27.95 which is old price

Comment: Looks like the website has been updated and no longer serves through AJAX. So, the only option remain is to render the page as suggested in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the page with requests-html:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA&DCC=IT&currency=EUR'

r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=2)
old_price = r.html.find('span.old-price', first=True)

print(old_price.text)
```

Output:

```sh
27,95€
```

### EDIT:

If you are using requests-html in jupyter:

```py
import nest_asyncio
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

nest_asyncio.apply()
url = 'https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA&DCC=IT&currency=EUR'
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

r = await asession.get(url)
await r.html.arender(sleep=2)

old_price = r.html.find('span.old-price', first=True)

print(old_price.text)
```

Output:

```sh
27,95€
```

Comment: Hey i am getting this error on line number `r.html.render(sleep=1)`  as :`RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.
`

Comment: Are you using jupyter ?

Comment: Yes i think i have to install some module  for that correct!

Comment: I will accept the answer after trying it for sure! Thank you for helping me out. :)

Comment: If you have multiple urls you can do it asynchronously. Hope it helps!